# Automapper com entidade relacionada

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

Boa tarde,

Como mapear as seguintes entidades

```
public class Artista
    {

        public Artista()
        {
            ArtistaCategoria = new List<ArtistaCategoria>();
        }

        public int ArtistaId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataAtualizacao { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ArtistaCategoria> ArtistaCategoria { get; set; }
    }


public class ArtistaCategoria
    {
        public int ArtistaCategoriaId { get; set; }
        public int ArtistaId { get; set; }
        public int CategoriaId { get; set; }

        public virtual Artista Artista { get; set; }
        public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    }


public class Categoria
    {

        public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ArtistaCategoria> ArtistaCategoria { get; set; }
    }
```

Estou utilizando Automapper e não estou conseguindo recuperar as categorias na listagem de artistas.

ex.

```
// aqui tenho as categorias
var a = _artistaApp.GetAll();

// após mapear, as categorias não são listadas
var aVM = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Artista>, IEnumerable<ArtistaViewModel>>(a);
```

Comment: Você configurou o mapeamento de Artista para `ArtistaViewModel` ?
ex: `Mapper.CreateMap<Artista>, ArtistaViewModel>...` e inicializou a configuração do `AutoMapper` no A`rtistaViewModel Global.asax` ?
Ou todas as propriedades são carregadas exceto as categorias ?

Comment: sim mapeamento configurado, e sim está configurado no global..